# Force the Dark Mode to only one UI Element in Swift by storyboard or programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, ios-darkmode

I want to set the dark mode fixed for one UI element.

So I want that all the app switch automatically from dark to light but one element in my case a UISegmentedControl stays in dark mode.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set `overrideUserInterfaceStyle` on the control to `.dark`.